# Regex with URLs - syntax

Tags: regex

We're using a proprietary tracking system that requires the use of regular expressions to load third party scripts on the URLs we specify.

I wanted to check the syntax of the regex we're using to see if it looks right.

To match the following URL

```
/products/18/indoor-posters
```

We are using this rule:

```
.*\/products\/18\/indoor-posters.*
```

Does this look right? Also, if there was a query parameter on the URL, would it still work? e.g.

```
/products/18/indoor-posters?someParam=someValue
```

There's another URL to match:

```
/products
```

The rule for this is:

```
.*\/products
```

Would this match correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, "right" is a relative term. Usually, `.*` is not a good idea because it matches anything, even nothing. So while these regexes will all match your example strings, they'll also match much more. The question is: What are you using the regexes *for*?

If you only want to check whether those substrings are present anywhere in the string, then they are fine (but then you don't need regex anyway, just check for substrings).

If you want to somehow check whether it's a valid URL, then no, the regexes are not fine because they'd also match `foo-bar!$%(§$§$/products/18/indoor-postersssssss)(/$%/§($/`.

If you can be sure that you'll always get a correct URL as your input and just want to check whether they match you pattern, then I'd suggest

```
^.*\/products$
```

to match any URL that ends in `/products`, and

```
^.*\/products\/18\/indoor-posters(?:\?[\w-]+=[\w-]+)?$
```

to match a URL that ends in `/products/18/indoor-posters` with an optional `?name=value` bit at the end, assuming only alphanumeric characters are legal for `name` and `value`.

Comment: The regexes are intended to match visitors on a given URL. So for instance, a visitor might hit the page at www.mysite.com/products and it's possible they might also have query parameters in the URL. We would only want to match a request URI that matches /products, optionally with query parameters denoted by ?a=b for instance.

Comment: Thanks for this - I think we're pretty much there. The parameter value would also need to support hyphens and underscores. How would we do that?

Comment: @thirtyish: `\w` already contains the underscore; I've added the hyphen.